# simplecov code coverage for my delayed_job tasks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, simplecov

Anyone know a way to get `simplecov` code coverage from my `delayed_job` jobs?  I'm using `minitest` and using `Delayed::Worker.new.work_off` to cause the job to run but the coverage stubbornly remains at zero.

Comment: try to use `group` [DOCs](https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov#groups)

Comment: Sorry, I may be being dumb but how does that help? `simplecov` does 'see' the files that contain my `delayed-job` jobs, files but it reports them as 0% covered.  I've got logging in these job files and the logging happens so clearly the jobs are being run.  Are you perhaps implying that these jobs are somehow being filtered out by DOCs somewhere?

Comment: I guess this files just filtered

Comment: Oh the embarrassment.  I've been happily running the integration test that hits the 'uncovered' code, but the test filename does not end in _test.  This means that minitest does not run this one test, which is why I'm not seeing any code coverage for it.

Comment: yep, simplecov counts only `_spec.rb` files